# SQL Query NOT Between Two Dates

Tags: sql, between

I need some help with SQL Query.

I am trying to select all records from table `test_table` which would not fit between two dates '2009-12-15' and '2010-01-02'.

This is my table structure:

```
`start_date` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
`end_date` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00'

-----------------------------
 **The following record should not be selected:**

`start_date`, `end_date`
'2003-06-04', '2010-01-01'
```

My query:

```
SELECT * 

FROM `test_table` 
WHERE 

CAST('2009-12-15' AS DATE) NOT BETWEEN start_date and end_date 
AND 
CAST('2010-01-02' AS DATE) NOT BETWEEN start_date and end_date
```

Any idea why my query select wrong records? Should I change the order of values in query to something like:

```
start_date NOT BETWEEN CAST('2009-12-15' AS DATE) and CAST('2010-01-02' AS DATE)
```

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: If you put NOT before start_date it should work.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

How about trying:

```
select * from 'test_table'
where end_date < CAST('2009-12-15' AS DATE)
or start_date > CAST('2010-01-02' AS DATE)
```

which will return all date ranges which do not overlap your date range at all.

Comment: I would advice against this, on even medium tables this will cause the query to become really slow.

Comment: @xnoise - and what, pray tell, is your alternative?

Comment: Can you please explain why "NOT BETWEEN" does not work here?

Comment: I have answered with a solution corresponding to @Xnoise 's suggestion

Answer (score 18):

Your logic is backwards.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    `test_table`
WHERE
        start_date NOT BETWEEN CAST('2009-12-15' AS DATE) and CAST('2010-01-02' AS DATE)
    AND end_date NOT BETWEEN CAST('2009-12-15' AS DATE) and CAST('2010-01-02' AS DATE)
```

Comment: This is the correct solution and should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 4):

If the 'NOT' is put before the start_date it should work. For some reason (I don't know why) when 'NOT' is put before 'BETWEEN' it seems to return everything.

```
NOT (start_date BETWEEN CAST('2009-12-15' AS DATE) AND CAST('2010-01-02' AS DATE))
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean that the date range of the selected rows should not lie fully within the specified date range?  In which case:

```
select *
from test_table
where start_date < date '2009-12-15'
or end_date > date '2010-01-02';
```

(Syntax above is for Oracle, yours may differ slightly).

Answer (score 1):

What you are currently doing is checking whether neither the start_date nor the end_date fall within the range of the dates given.

I guess what you are really looking for is a record which does not *fit* in the date range given. If so, use the query below.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM `test_table` 
    WHERE  CAST('2009-12-15' AS DATE) > start_date  AND  CAST('2010-01-02' AS DATE) < end_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that start_date is before end_date,

interval [start_date..end_date] NOT BETWEEN two dates simply means that either it starts before 2009-12-15 or it ends after 2010-01-02.

Then you can simply do

```
start_date<CAST('2009-12-15' AS DATE) or end_date>CAST('2010-01-02' AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

For there to be an overlap the table's start_date has to be LESS THAN the interval end date (i.e. it has to start before the end of the interval) AND the table's end_date has to be GREATER THAN the interval start date.  You may need to use <= and >= depending on your requirements.